# Rename multiple files while keeping the same extension on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, file, awk, rename

I have 100s of files in a directory with the following naming convention.

```
00XYZCD042ABCDE20141002ABCDE.XML
00XYZCC011ABCDE20141002.TXT
00XYZCB165ABCDE20141002ABCDE.TXT
00XYZCB165ABCDE20141002ABCDE.CSV
```

I want to rename these files using `bash`, `awk`, `cut`, `sed`, so that I get the output:

```
XYZCD042.XML
XYZCC011.TXT
XYZCB165.TXT
XYZCB165.CSV
```

So basically, remove the first two 0s always, and then keep everything until ABCDE starts and then remove everything including ABCDE and keep the file extension.

Answer (score 7):

Bash only:

```
for fn in *; do
    A=${fn#00}
    mv $fn ${A/ABCDE*./.}
done
```

The first line in the for loop strips the 00 prefix, and the second line strips the ABCDE suffix (up to a dot), then performs the rename.

Comment: +1, just pointing out that it also works for zsh and ksh and probably some others I can't think of.

Comment: This would be a `rockin'` answer if you added explanation.

Comment: Brilliant solution, just one question, can this A=${fn#00} be changed to take any two digits instead of 00?

Comment: apparently this works :  A=${fn#[0-9][0-9]}
how about if ABCDE in the second line is not always ABCDE but variable? is there any regular expression for that please? thought [a-z] might work , but didn't. thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You should figure out what form that variable takes and write an appropriate expression. Since you didn't specify anything about variability in your question, I can't help you there.

Answer (score 7):

You could try the below `rename` command,

```
rename 's/ABCDE.*(\..*)/$1/;s/^00//' *
```

**Explanation:**

- `s/ABCDE.*(\..*)/$1/` Matches all the characters from the first `ABCDE` upto the last and captures only the extension part. Then all the matched chars are replaced with that captured extension.
- `s/^00//` Then this would remove the leading two zeros.

Answer (score 4):

```
for file in *
do
    mv -- "$file" "${file:2:8}.${file#*.}"
done
```

It's important to always quote your variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind and understand all of the effects.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in *; do
    mv $i $(echo $i | sed -e 's/^00//' -e 's/ABCDE2014[^.]*//');
done
```