# copy and rename file in linux bash

Tags: linux, file-rename, file-copying

I'd like to copy and rename multiple files within the same folder. Just like I have the files
*foo.c foo.h* and want to use them as a template for new files named *bar.c bar.h*.

```
cp foo.* bar.*
```

would describe what I mean but won't work.

using *rename* will just overwrite the old files.

Is there some simple solution for this or do I have to create a whole script that opens a folder in /tmp, copy there, rename there and move back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files, but only rename part of the filename in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20657432/608639), [Rename multiple files while keeping the same extension on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26178469/608639), [Rename file while keeping the extension in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46264427/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer myself with that wonderful tool mcp

```
mcp 'foo.*' 'bar.#1'
```

Comment: got an error that bash: mcp: command not found

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple `for` loop and some [string manipulation](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

```
#!/bin/bash
# for each file following the pattern "foo."
for i in foo.* 
do 
    # copy file to "bar" + original extension
    cp $i bar.${i#foo.} 
done
```